# raise an exception with mock_open for builts.open

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following function:

```
 def detail():
   try:
      with open('file1.txt') as data:
         return data.read()
   except FileNotFoundError:
        return None
```

I am trying to make sure it returns None when file is not found but missing it out:

```
import unittest
from mock import patch, mock_open
import detail

class TestDetail(unittest.TestCase):
    open_ = mock_open(read_data = raise FileNotFoundError)
    with patch.object(__builtin__, "open", open_):
        content = detail("dummyfile.txt")
        self.assetEqual(content, None)
```

but it is not working

Comment: what error are you seeing? Can you be more elaborate on what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the question, but I think you could simply check if the file exists with the os module

```
import os.path

if os.path.isfile(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r") as data:
        return data.read()
else:
    return None
```

EDIT: It is more effective to use a basic if statement when possible rather than a try block.

Comment: assume the above is in a function. how would you write a unit test for it?

Comment: Assuming the function is called `read_file`, here is the test for reading a file that does not exist: `self.assertIsNone(read_file("file that does not exist"))`. If the file exists, we shouldn't get None: `self.assertIsNotNone(read_file("file that exists"))`.